# 0% Code coverage for custom campaign influence trigger

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have implemented Custom Campaign Influence Models and wrote a trigger based on the instruction on https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000265934&language=en_US&type=1. The trigger works fine, but my Apex test class does not get any trigger coverage.

The fundamental problem is that when a new Opportunity is created, the process of creating/updating campaign influence (CI) records executes as a separate concurrent transaction that runs under "Salesforce Administrator” and the CI records are not available immediately. In other words, it does not seem possible to test the custom campaign influence (CCI) trigger with normal logic, something like …

- create an opportunity
- SF trigger runs automatically and creates/updates CI records =>  my trigger runs because CI records were created/updated
- verify that CCI records were created (but really it cannot be verified in the same test class)

As I mentioned, I get 0% coverage for my trigger using this logic, but I know that other people were able to implement CCIs, so there has to be a different way of testing.

Here is my test code:

```
@isTest
public class CampaignInfluenceTriggerTest {

    @testSetup static void setup() { 
        // Create common test accounts 
        Account acct = new Account ( 
            Name = 'Test, Inc.'); 
        insert acct; 
        System.debug('Inserted Account, ID: ' + acct.id); 

        // create Lead 
        Lead lead = new Lead( 
            Company = 'Nike-TEST13', 
            LastName = 'Smith', 
            Status = 'Responded'); 
        insert lead; 
        System.debug('Inserted Lead, ID: ' + lead.id); 

        // create Campaign 
        Campaign camp = new Campaign( 
            Name = 'Test', 
            IsActive = TRUE); 
        insert camp; 
        System.debug('Inserted Campaign, ID: ' + camp.id); 

        // create Campaign Member 
        CampaignMember member = new CampaignMember( 
            LeadId = lead.Id, 
            Status = 'Contact', 
            CampaignId = camp.Id); 
        insert member; 
        System.debug('Inserted Member, ID: ' + member.id); 

        // convert Lead 
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert(); 
        lc.setLeadId(lead.Id); 
        lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(False); 
        lc.setConvertedStatus('Contact'); 
        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc); 

        // query new Opportunity 
        Id oppId = lcr.getOpportunityId(); 
        Opportunity thisOpp = [ 
            SELECT Id, AccountId, Name 
            FROM Opportunity 
            WHERE Id = :oppId 
            LIMIT 1 
        ]; 
        System.debug('thisOpp = ' + thisOpp.Id); 
        System.debug('thisOpp AccountId = ' + thisOpp.AccountId); 
        System.debug('thisOpp Name = ' + thisOpp.Name); 

        // query new Contact 
        Id conId = lcr.getContactId(); 
        Contact thisCon = [ 
            SELECT Id 
            FROM Contact 
            WHERE Id = :conId 
            LIMIT 1 
        ]; 
        System.debug('thisCon = ' + thisCon.Id); 
    } 

    @isTest static void testInsert() { 
        // Get account 
        Account acct = [
            SELECT Id 
            FROM Account 
            WHERE Name='Test, Inc.' 
            LIMIT 1
        ]; 
        System.debug('Account Id = ' + acct.Id);

        // Get contact 
        Contact con = [
            SELECT Id 
            FROM Contact 
            WHERE LastName = 'Smith' 
            LIMIT 1
        ]; 
        System.debug('Contact Id = ' + con.Id);

        // Get opportunty
        Opportunity opp = [
            SELECT Id 
            FROM Opportunity 
            WHERE Name = 'Nike-TEST13' 
            LIMIT 1
        ]; 
        System.debug('Opportunity Id = ' + opp.Id);

        // Get Campaign 
        Campaign camp = [
            SELECT Id 
            FROM Campaign 
            WHERE Name='Test' 
            LIMIT 1
        ]; 
        System.debug('Campaign Id = ' + camp.Id);

        // Verify that custom campaign influence records were created
        String customModelId = '03V5B00000000HqUAI';
        CampaignInfluence[] SFcamp = [ 
            SELECT campaignId, ContactId, OpportunityId 
            FROM CampaignInfluence 
            WHERE campaignId = :camp.Id  
            AND modelId = :customModelId
            AND contactId = :con.Id            
            AND Opportunity.id = :opp.Id
        ];         

        System.assert(SFcamp != null);
     }

}
```

Trigger:

```
    trigger CampaignInfluenceTrigger on CampaignInfluence (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    CampaignInfluenceHandler handler = new CampaignInfluenceHandler();

    if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
        Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
        ids.addAll(trigger.newMap.keySet());
        handler.addCustomCampaign(Trigger.new, ids);
    }
    else if (Trigger.isDelete) {
        //handler.deleteCustomCampaign(Trigger.old);
    }
}
```

Handler:

```
    public without sharing class CampaignInfluenceHandler {

    // Define campaign Influence model ids
    String sfModelId = '03V5B0000000014UAA';
    String customModelId = '03V5B00000000HqUAI';

    public void addCustomCampaign(List<CampaignInfluence> TriggerNew, Set<Id> ids) {
            System.debug('CampaignInfluence Trigger isInsert isUpdate');

        // List trigger influence campaign records
        CampaignInfluence[] triggerCamp = TriggerNew; 
        String opportunityID = triggerCamp[0].OpportunityId;

        // List existing custom influence campaign records
        CampaignInfluence[] customCamp = [
            SELECT campaignId, ContactId, OpportunityId  
            FROM CampaignInfluence
            WHERE Opportunity.id = :opportunityID
            AND modelId = :customModelId
        ];

        // Define Primary campaign
        Opportunity primary = [
            SELECT CampaignId 
            FROM Opportunity 
            WHERE id = :opportunityID
        ];

        // Calculate total number of campaigns
         //Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
         //ids.addAll(trigger.newMap.keySet());
        Integer customNcampaigns = customCamp.size();
        Integer triggerNcampaigns = ids.size();
        Integer nCampaigns = triggerNcampaigns + customNcampaigns;

        // combine existing custom campaigns with newly inserted campaigns
        /*CampaignInfluence[] allCamp = new List<CampaignInfluence>();
        allCamp.addAll(customCamp);
        allCamp.addAll(triggerCamp);*/

        // List all contact roles
        Id[] allContactIds = new List<Id>();
        for (CampaignInfluence ci: triggerCamp) { 
            allContactIds.add(ci.contactId); 
        }
        Id[] customContactIds = new List<Id>();
        for (CampaignInfluence ci: customCamp) { 
            allContactIds.add(ci.contactId); 
        }

        // Define First campaign
        CampaignMember first= [
            SELECT campaign.Id 
            FROM CampaignMember
            WHERE Contact.id IN :allContactIds
            ORDER BY id ASC
            LIMIT 1
        ];

        // Define influence percentage logic
        Double influencePercentage;
        Double primaryPercentage;
        Double firstPercentage;  
        Double otherPercentage;

        if (nCampaigns == 1) {
           primaryPercentage = 100.0;
           firstPercentage = 100.0;
           otherPercentage = 100.0;
        }
        else if (nCampaigns == 2) {
            if (primary.campaignId == first.campaign.id) {
                primaryPercentage = 90.0;
                firstPercentage = 90.0;
                otherPercentage = 10.0;            
            }
            else {
                primaryPercentage = 70.0;
                firstPercentage = 30.0; 
                otherPercentage = 30.0;
            }        
        }
        else if (nCampaigns >= 3) {
            if (primary.campaignId == first.campaign.id) {
                primaryPercentage = 86.67;
                firstPercentage = 86.67;
                otherPercentage = 6.67;            
            }
            else {
                primaryPercentage = 66.67;
                firstPercentage = 26.67;
                otherPercentage = 6.67;                        
            }        
        }           

       // Create a new list of CampaignInfluence records
       CampaignInfluence[] newCamp = new List<CampaignInfluence>();
       for(CampaignInfluence ci: triggerCamp){

           // Skip iteration for existing CampaignInfluence records in custom model
           if (ci.modelId == customModelId) return;

           // Skip iteration if there is no contact
           if(String.isBlank(ci.contactId)) return;           

           // Create new CampaignInfluence records and add them to the List for insert
           CampaignInfluence newCI = new CampaignInfluence();       

           newCI.modelId = customModelId;
           newCI.contactId = ci.contactId;                        
           newCI.opportunityId = ci.opportunityId;
           newCI.campaignId = ci.campaignId;

           if (newCI.campaignId == primary.CampaignId) {
               influencePercentage = primaryPercentage;
           }
           else if (newCI.campaignId == first.campaign.id)  {
               influencePercentage = firstPercentage;
           }
           else {
               influencePercentage = otherPercentage;
           }

           newCI.Influence = influencePercentage;

           // Add newly created or updated records to the new list
           newCamp.add(newCI);
       }

        // Insert or update the records if the list if not empty
       if(!newCamp.isEmpty()){
           upsert newCamp;
           System.debug( newCamp.size() + ' custom campaign influence records created.');
       }        

       // update existing custom influence records
       if(!customCamp.isEmpty()){
           for(CampaignInfluence ci: customCamp){           
               if (ci.campaignId == primary.CampaignId) {
                   influencePercentage = primaryPercentage;
               }
               else if (ci.campaignId == first.campaign.id)  {
                   influencePercentage = firstPercentage;
               }
               else {
                   influencePercentage = otherPercentage;
               }
               ci.Influence = influencePercentage;              
           }       

           // Update the records if the list if not empty
           update customCamp;   
           System.debug( newCamp.size() + ' custom campaign influence records updated.');            
        }
    }

    /*public void deleteCustomCampaign(List<CampaignInfluence> TriggerOld) {
        // List trigger influence campaign records
        CampaignInfluence[] triggerCamp = TriggerOld; 
        String opportunityID = triggerCamp[0].OpportunityId;

       CampaignInfluence[] deleteCamp = new List<CampaignInfluence>();
       for(CampaignInfluence ci: triggerCamp){       

           // List custom influence campaign records to delete
            CampaignInfluence deleteCI = [
                SELECT Id  
                FROM CampaignInfluence
                WHERE Opportunity.id = :opportunityID
                AND contactId = :ci.ContactId
                AND campaignId = :ci.campaignId
                AND modelId = :customModelId
                LIMIT 1
            ];  

           // Add record to be deleted to the list
           deleteCamp.add(deleteCI);
       } 

        // delete custom influence records
        try {
            delete deleteCamp;
        } catch (DmlException e) {
            // Process exception here
        }
    }*/

}
```

Comment: Without seeing the code you are trying to test, it is very difficult to assist you. Please **[edit]** this post to include your trigger code.

Comment: Hi. I have added the code below.

Answer (score 2):

This was too much for a comment and I don't know that it completely answers your question, but I think you'll find it helpful.

It seems that you could save yourself a LOT of trouble testing this if you considered that Campaigns can have Contacts as well as Leads. In that way you'd avoid having to go through the exercise of Lead conversion, Account creation, etc.

Its not entirely clear when this trigger is expected to execute, but it seems to me that it's the creation of the Opportunity (perhaps before insert) that causes the chain of events to execute that you're trying to test.

There are other things I'm aware of that you may need to also consider in this. If I'm not mistaken, the Opportunity close date needs to fall within xx number of days from the end of the Campaign for a Campaign to have any influence on the Opportunity. At least that applies to the standard Campaign Influence rules. I'm going to assume those either can or are being altered by your trigger.

The document you referenced noted the model's influence records are recalculated when any of the following events occur:

> - Changing any Customizable Campaign Influence setting
> - Updating an opportunity’s Close Date
> - Adding or removing members from campaigns
> - Deleting or undeleting accounts or opportunities

The docs went on to say that this can cause duplicate record creation so be sure to include validation checks in your code to make certain you're not inserting a record with the same modelId + opptyId + campaignId + contactId into the same model and that if a record already exists, perform an update operation on the record instead. If your code has done that, you'll need at least two unit test methods to test it properly.

**EDIT**

After seeing your code, it appears to me that you need to add some additional code to an opportunity trigger to cause it to fire to begin with. What I'm referring to is that you don't have anything that causes `CampaignInfluence` to want to either insert or update. What does that? It's the insert of the Opportunity that has a ContactId related to the Campaign!

That means you need to add afterInsert code to an Opportunity trigger where you can relate Contact, OpportunityContactRole (or so I'd expect), and Campaign Influence. Once you've done that, it should cause a cascade to occur where the CampaignInfluence Trigger will execute. I'd expect you might need (if possible) to add the Campaign to the Campaign Influence for the new Opportunity, but don't know if your custom system allows you to do that. If not, your Contact needs to retain an association with the Campaign.